# CSS padding is not applied to the div in react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, flexbox

I have a div like this in react js which renders multiple divs and overflows :

```
 <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        padding: "1em 0.7em",
        overflowX: "auto",
        width: "100%",
        direction: "rtl",
        background: "#ef394e"
      }}
    >
      {Array.from(Array(10).keys()).map((each, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          className="swiper-slide"
          style={{
            background: "white",
            borderRadius: "10px",
            width: "270px",
            margin: "0 .4em"
          }}
        >
          <div style={{ padding: "2em 6em" }}>Hello</div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
```

But for some reason the padding is applied to the containers right side but not the left side here are some pictures :
[image: image-one]

[image: image-two]

How can I apply padding to the array item's container div for both the left and right sides ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `div` width bigger then the body,
and as result your body also have scroll.
Try add `boxSizing: border-box` to your parent component, and the body scroll will disappear.

```
const App = () => {
 return (
   <div
     style={{
       display: "flex",
       padding: "1em 0em",
       overflowX: "auto",
       width: "100%",
       direction: "rtl",
       background: "#ef394e",
       boxSizing: "border-box" // <--- this line
     }}
   >
   ...
   </div>
 );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the padding on the div. It's to little and the margin too.

```js
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        padding: "1em 0em",
        overflowX: "auto",
        width: "100%",
        direction: "rtl",
        background: "#ef394e"
      }}
    >
      {Array.from(Array(10).keys()).map((each, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          className="swiper-slide"
          style={{
            background: "white",
            borderRadius: "10px",
            width: "270px",
            margin: "0 .4em"
          }}
        >
          <div style={{ padding: "2em 6em" }}>Hello</div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: My problem is the parent div padding is only applied to the right side and not the left side .

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to save changes. I missed a 0 on the padding. Test now.